# How to determine whether SqlConnection is enlisted into a System.Transactions' tx or not?

Tags: .net, ado.net, .net-2.0, transactions, msdtc

When we using a transation from System.Transactions (creating TransationScope for an instance) by default all Sql-connections (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection) (but is't also the true for Oracle.DataAccess.OracleConnection) are enlisted on opening.
That's called auto-enlistment. Nice feature. But it can be turned off throught a connection string's parameter (enlist=false). In that case connection being opened wouldn't be enlisted.
But it can be enlisted manually later.
So my question is: for some given SqlConnection's instance how can I determine whether that connection is enlisted or not (into an System.Transaction).
I can look at connection string for the parameter. But this won't do because as I said connection could be enlisted manually.

Comment: Good question.  My scenario is that I have an assembly that is just a bucket of static methods that take an open SqlConnection and CRUD on it.  It would be nice to enforce that the SqlConnection be enlisted in a transaction before continuing, to help protect against app-level logical corruption by the caller.  We can detect a `Transaction.Current != null` and we can detect `SqlConnection conn != null`, but we can't test to see if the conn is enlisted in a transaction.

Answer (score 11):

The framework doesn't appear to allow that.

Perhaps we could discuss why you need to know this information?  The TransactionScopeOptions give you some flexibility about when to create transactions.

However, refusing "no" for an answer, a little source browsing later and I've created this code, which DOES work.  Note, that this code could cease to function at anytime with patches to the framework!!!!

```
    static bool IsEnlisted(SqlConnection sqlConnection)
    {
        object innerConnection = typeof(SqlConnection).GetField("_innerConnection", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy).GetValue(sqlConnection);
        var enlistedTransactionField =
            EnumerateInheritanceChain(innerConnection.GetType())
            .Select(t => t.GetField("_enlistedTransaction", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy))
            .Where(fi => fi != null)
            .First();
        object enlistedTransaction = enlistedTransactionField.GetValue(innerConnection);
        return enlistedTransaction != null;
    }

    static IEnumerable<Type> EnumerateInheritanceChain(Type root)
    {
        for (Type current = root; current != null; current = current.BaseType)
            yield return current;
    }
```

Again, this is making use of private variables and internal classes within the .NET framework.  While it works today, it may not tomorrow.